# Android google maps + sliding menu, implementation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am beginner in programming and I've tried to implement the google maps inside sliding menu, at home, this is the fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.moictab.decanias.MapActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<fragment 

          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

          />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the class I want to put the maps

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        android.app.FragmentTransaction mTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SupportMapFragment mFRaFragment = new MapFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putDouble("lat", -4.573362);
        args.putDouble("lng", -44.6020426);
        mFRaFragment.setArguments(args);
        mTransaction.add(R.id.map, mFRaFragment);
        mTransaction.commit();


        MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());


        return rootView;
    }
```

}

But I am getting these errors

```
mTransaction.add(R.id.map, mFRaFragment);
```

The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, SupportMapFragment)

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
```

The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type HomeFragment

The solution would be:

```
public class HomeFragment extends FragmentActivity {
```

And everything stay okay in this class, but in MainActivity is not acceptable because there is extends Fragment, I already tried to change there to FragmentActivity, but the the replace doesn't work:

```
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

message: "The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragmentActivity)"

I already tried to use android.support.v4.app.Fragment, but it doesn't work too.
My problem is to implement the google maps android in navigation Drawer.

```
/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

I have seen too many ways to do, but they don't work, like this as well:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

and also import

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
Before you do this Right click project->properties->buildpath->java build path -> libraries .. then click on add external jars

the go to

```
\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4

and select android-support-v4.jar
```

Comment: Hi.. Did you find the solution?? Did you implement slide menu with google maps??

Comment: Yes, I did it, mate. Do you need help?

Comment: Now i found the solution. But struck in getting gps location and showing in map. My app is working fine in emulator. But when i try to run the app in samsung note the app getting crash. :-(

Comment: Here's my email: mdq767@gmail.com. Give me the pleasure to try help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As been stated by the error you receive:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:

```
<meta-data 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

So you need to add this meta-data element to you Manifest file under the application hive:

```
<meta-data 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```